# why i fail to read the xml values?

Tags: c#

this is my xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Configuration>
   <el1>
     <Id>1</Id>
   </el1>
   <el2>
     <ip>1.2.3.4</ip>
     <port>1</port>
  </el2>
</Configuration>
```

I trying to read the values with this code:

```
    public ReadXml(string xmlPath)
    {
            try
            {
                XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(configFilePath);

                XElement elm1 = xDoc.Element("el1");    // get elm1 == null
                XElement elm2 = xDoc.Element("el2");    // get elm2 == null





            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _log.Error("Fail to load", e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first available node is the Configuration node. Look at the child nodes for your first node and it should work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Select root element first then child

```
public ReadXml(string xmlPath)
    {
            try
            {
                XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(configFilePath);

                XElement root = xDoc.Element("Configuration");    // select root
                XElement elm1 = root.Element("el1");    // get elm1 == null
                XElement elm2 = root.Element("el2");    // get elm2 == null





            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _log.Error("Fail to load", e);
            }
        }
    }
```